# What is the correct way to call a C++ template base class's constructor

Tags: c++

I have an issue related to calling a constructor in the template base class from a derived class.

```
template <typename Curve> struct LogNormalCurve: TEvolveCurve<Curve, QMaths::LNProcess>
{
#ifndef _MSC_VER
    LogNormalCurve(std::shared_ptr<Curve> curve) : TEvolveCurve<Curve, QMaths::LNProcess>(curve) {}
#else
    LogNormalCurve(std::shared_ptr<Curve> curve) : TEvolveCurve(curve) {}
#endif
};
```

So LogNormalCurve derives from TEvolveCurve where it's a template class with two arguments.

I need to insert an ugly _MSC_VER to the code because Visual Studio 2013 only compiles with "`TEvolveCurve(curve)`" while XCode is only able to compile with "`TEvolveCurve<Curve, QMaths::LNProcess>`".

I'm using the default C++11 compilers.

Comment: I think the first way is correct, but I can't find any citation on the webterspherez.

Comment: I think so as well, but it doesn't work on VS2013. I'm wondering anyway to get rid of the stupid _MSC_VER.

Comment: You need to change the class declaration code also to use `#ifdef MSC_VER`. Don't you?

Comment: You could always just inherit all the constructors from the base class, seeing as though you just forward the arguments: `using TEvolveCurve<Curve, QMaths::LNProcess>::TevolveCurve;`

Comment: No. Only the derived class as shown. The base class is a just a standard simple C++ template class.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I need to call the base class's constructor. The base class has no default constructor.

Comment: Visual studio compilers do not comply to the standard very well when it comes to templates. If it compiles on GCC and not on MSVC, then it's probably correct.

Comment: @StudentT the `using` method will inherit **all** of the base classes constructors, not just the default constructor. The signature of the base-class constructor will be inherited and you will be able to construct your derived type using the same arguments you would on the base class.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement) (scroll down until you see the `using BaseClass::BaseClass;`)

Comment: @Smith_61 removing "when it comes to templates" would be an equally, if not more, qualified statement. I'd add `clang` to that list of things to test. If it passes `gcc` *and* `clang`, but pukes on `msvc`, its *highly* likely an ms faux-pas.

Comment: @WhozCraig I prefer to think that instead of not following the standard, they are just following a standard we haven't heard of yet. MSVC is just the hipster compiler.

Comment: You could try putting `typedef TEvolveCurve<Curve, QMaths::LNProcess> Base;` just inside the class, then specify the constructor as `LogNormalCurve(std::shared_ptr<Curve> curve) : Base(curve) {}`